# Where am I going wrong when attempting to evaluate the integral $\int { x\ln(1+x)dx } $?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am being asked to make a substitution and to then evaluate the following integral using integration by parts.

$$\int { x\ln(1+x)\,dx } $$

Here is everything that I have done thus far:

$u=(1+x)$

$du = 1dx$

So, we substitute and get:

$$\int { (u-1)\ln(u)\,du } $$

Now we use integration by parts:

Let $f(u)=\ln(u)$, $f'(u)=\frac { 1 }{ u }$, $g(u)=\frac { u^2 }{ 2 } -u$, $g'(u)=(u-1)$

So, we now get:

$$\int { (u-1)\ln(u) } \,du=\ln(u)(\frac { u^{ 2 } }{ 2 } -u)-\int { \frac { 1 }{ u }  } (\frac { u^{ 2 } }{ 2 } -u)\,du$$

$$=\ln(u)(\frac { u^{ 2 } }{ 2 } -u)-\int { (\frac { u }{ 2 } -1)\,du }$$

So, we finally get:
$$\int { (u-1)\ln(u) } \,du=\ln(u)(\frac { u^{ 2 } }{ 2 } -u)-\frac { u^{ 2 } }{ 4 } +u+C$$

Now we replace $u$ back with $(1+x)$ and get:

$$\int { x\ln(1+x)\,dx } =\ln(1+x)(\frac { (1+x)^{ 2 } }{ 2 } -(1+x))-\frac { (1+x)^{ 2 } }{ 4 } +(1+x)+C$$

$$=\ln(1+x)(\frac { x^{ 2 }+2x+1 }{ 2 } +\frac { -2-2x }{ 2 } )-\frac { (x^{ 2 }+2x+1) }{ 4 } +\frac { (4x+4) }{ 4 } +C$$

$$=\ln(1+x)\cdot \frac { (x^{ 2 }-1) }{ 2 } +\frac { -x^{ 2 }+2x+3 }{ 4 } +C$$

At this point I can't seem to match my answer with any online integral calculator or wolfram alpha. I am not sure of where I went wrong. I would appreciate any hints/guidance.

Comment: Looks good to me.  Remember that there's no point to keeping that $3$ in the numerator...$\frac 34$ is just an additive constant which we can absorb into the $C$.  It's not wrong to have it there but it is distracting and unhelpful.

Comment: I don't see a mistake at all. Can you please add in your question the output of Wolfram Alpha to this question. We can work it together.

Comment: Just did it In Wolfram Alpha and got $\frac 14\times  \left(2 (x^2-1) \ln(x+1)-(x-2) x\right)+constant$ which is equivalent to your expression.

Comment: @lulu I never knew that about no point in keeping the $3$. This applies to all constants that get left behind when evaluating indefinite integrals? 

I believe that the reason I was thinking that I made a mistake somewhere was because wolfram alpha (and other integral calculators) would leave out the $3$ in the numerator as you already mentioned.

Comment: That's what I guessed.  Yes...stray additive constants that appear can be absorbed into the $C$.    Makes for confusion sometimes...if your integral came out $\sin^2(x)+C$ another method might give $-\cos^2(x)+C$.  As the two functions differ by an additive $+1$ the derivatives coincide.

Comment: @lulu Wow! I just spent one hour, and 3 sheets of engineering paper on a single problem all because of such a stupid mistake on my part. I should have came here for guidance/help sooner. Thank you for your help. Please feel free to add your answer(s) below. I will be sure to accept it and +1 as soon as you add it. Once again, thank you!

Comment: You did all the hard work, I just reviewed it.  I think I can safely assure you that every person who writes for this site has spent hours stuck on points more or less like this one.